# Is there somewhere I can write configuration files from my program without root access?

Tags: permissions, filesystems

I'm writing a small utility, and I have to put the configuration files somewhere.  From looking into it, it seems like `/etc` would be the cannonical location in Linux.  But I'm running into the issue that this directory seems to require root access to write to by default.

Is there anywhere which is possible to write to without needing to call my program with `sudo`?  For instance `homebrew` on mac seems to be able to write to `/usr/local/bin` somehow without root access.

I know I could put things in `/home` but I'm trying to do things the "right way" in terms of where files should be stored in Linux.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do thing the right way, the program and its configuration files must not be user editable because otherwise it breaks the standard security model.

Either it's owned by the user and thus its configuration is stored in the user home directory or it's installed in any system location (e.g. `/usr/bin`, `/usr/local/bin`, `/opt/appname`) and then its configuration is stored again in some of system locations (e.g. `/etc`, `/usr/local/etc` or `/opt/appname/etc`) as well.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a subdirectory, probably hidden, specific to your application, like `.myApp`. It might also contain version and installation logs. This makes it much easier to clean up etc.

If the config is shared across users, you can do a one-off sudo mkdir in a "shared space" and give the relevant permissions within that directory. It won't matter that levels above are not writeable.

If your config is per user, your app creates `.myApp` under the user's /home/username on installation or first use.

There is an official Filesystem Hierarchy Standard for Linux.